buildcacheid() error on login/submission
Here are some contextual elements :
Drupal 10.2.5   (contents (and users)  where imported from a V7 drupal old site
Php 8.1.27
ldap_auth 8.x-40.3
All pages of the site are restricted to authenticated users.
So whatever page is requested, the anonymous user is redirected to the /user/login page.
After entering the login/password, Drupal returns the following error page from the same route (/user/login)
Le site Web a rencontré une erreur inattendue.
Error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList could not be converted to string in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->buildCacheId() (line 145 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityStorageBase.php).
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->getFromStaticCache() (Line: 286)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->loadMultiple() (Line: 266)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->load() (Line: 62)
Drupal\media\Plugin\QueueWorker\ThumbnailDownloader->processItem() (Line: 268)
Drupal\Core\Cron->processQueue() (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Cron->processQueues() (Line: 162)
Drupal\Core\Cron->run() (Line: 75)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Cron->run() (Line: 65)
Drupal\automated_cron\EventSubscriber\AutomatedCron->onTerminate()
call_user_func() (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 115)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminate() (Line: 63)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->terminate() (Line: 688)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->terminate() (Line: 700)
ldap_auth_form_alter_submit()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 82)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->executeValidateHandlers() (Line: 275)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->doValidateForm() (Line: 118)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidator->validateForm() (Line: 593)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm() (Line: 325)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (Line: 73)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 627)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext() (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 181)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 76)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 28)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 32)
Drupal\big_pipe\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle() (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass() (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 36)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 704)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)
By refreshing the page, we see that the user is indeed authenticated and the page initially requested is displayed.
I noticed that the same error was well logged by the ldap_auth module.
And appears also when cron tasks are running...
is there a way to identifu the item for which the problem appears ?

What happens after the user got logged in? Redirect to where? This page then is displaying a field which seems to trigger the error. Are your user accounts filled with additional fields? Hide all fields from output and retry. Some field being output in the header, footer, somewhere else on the page? Hide them and retry. Debugging is what you need to do before asking a question. Otherwise it's just back and forth clarification and wild guessing, which doesn't fit this Q+A format. Try to isolate the error systematically. Switch themes, switch modules on and off, switch PHP versions etc.
